# Program printing % after expected output

Tags: c++, file-io

I am new to C++ and just ran my first program. The problem is that the output has a '%' after the expected output. 
I have installed LLVM using Homebrew,
`brew install llvm` 
I have tried compiling with clang++ (installed with llvm) as well as g++ (macOS default).

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::cout << "Yo!";
        return 0;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::cout << "Hello";
        return 0;
}
```

[Output for both programs using clang++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdN0m.png) 
Thanks!

Comment: isn't the % sign the shell prompt? Try outputting a newline after the string: "Hello\n"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '%' is printed by your shell (probably Zsh?) after a program finishes without printing a newline character as the last character of its output.

To prevent this, output a newline:

```
std::cout << "Hello\n";
```

Comment: Thanks! I am indeed using ZSH. Is there a way to disable the %?

Comment: You don't have to disable it. You program prints "hello" without a line return. When it ends, ZSH "starts" again and prints % (its prompt). What you want is to "print" a line return in program so that ZSH prints % on the next line (and not just after your text)

Comment: Apperently `PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''` in your .zshrc should prevent the '%' from being printed (have not tested this myself).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! @TonvandenHeuvel